# Add User to Database not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm really new to ASP.net and I am currently trying to create a registration page on a site. I was successful in adding a user to the database but I decided to add another feature into the code to check what userID's were available. For example, if a user deleted their account their userID would become available for use again. I'm trying to find the min value and the max value and add or subtract 1 depending on whether it is min or max. I can run the code I have written for this with no errors but the user is not added to the database. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing from my code to do this?

EDIT >>>>>
Code adds a user to database but it adds the new user at -1 instead. I don't seem to be able to see where the issue is.

```
If (aDataReader2.Read() = False) Then
  aConnection1 = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
  aConnection1.Open()
  aQuery = "Insert Into UserDetails "
  aQuery = aQuery & "Values ('" & userID & "','" & userFName & "','" & userLName & "','" & userEmail & "','" & userUsername & "','" & userPassword & "')"
  aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection1)
  aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  aConnection1.Close()
ElseIf (min = 1) Then
  aConnection2 = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
  aConnection2.Open()
  aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery3, aConnection2)
  aDataReader2 = aCommand.ExecuteReader()
  userID = max + 1
  aQuery = "Insert Into UserDetails "
  aQuery = aQuery & "Values ('" & userID & "','" & userFName & "','" & userLName & "','" & userEmail & "','" & userUsername & "','" & userPassword & "')"
  aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection2)
  aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  aConnection2.Close()
Else
  aConnection3 = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
  aConnection3.Open()
  aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery2, aConnection3)
  aDataReader2 = aCommand.ExecuteReader
  userID = min - 1
  aQuery = "Insert Into UserDetails "
  aQuery = aQuery & "Values ('" & userID & "','" & userFName & "','" & userLName & "','" & userEmail & "','" & userUsername & "','" & userPassword & "')"
  aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection3)
  aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  aConnection3.Close()
  lblResults.Text = "User Account successfully created"
  btnCreateUser.Enabled = False
End If
```

Here's the code I used to get the max and min values from the database. I'm getting a value of 0 for both of them - when min should be 1 and max should be 5

```
 Dim minID As Integer
 Dim maxID As Integer
 aQuery2 = "Select Min(UserID) AS '" & [minID] & "' From UserDetails"
 aQuery3 = "Select Max(UserID) AS ' " & [maxID] & "' From UserDetails"
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It isn't recomendable to reuse the old ids.

Comment: Thanks John. Adripanico I wouldn't have thought so either but it is something my lecturer has recommended to the class to get an A grade

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the code and watching the code to see which path it follows and what the values are at run-time?

Comment: I have Lost Hobbit. I outputted what Max and Min are and they are coming out as 0 - which is wrong. I think that's why it isn't working properly. I've added the code I used to get the max and min values in my original post

Comment: It won't let me. It says I need 15 reputation to be able to vote up

Comment: Your existing code is vulnerable to sql injection. It is **never** okay to substitute sql query _data_ into the sql code via string concatenation like this. Learn about parameterized queries. This is incredibly important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what
t the problem is exactly, since we see only a part of it. Where do min and max come from?

I cannot give you a solution, however, I suggest you to structure your code better. You have a lot (!) of redundant code. This makes the code difficult to read, to understand, to change and to test.

Put the user data into a class. This makes it easier to handle than a lot of individual variables.

```
Public Class User
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property EMail As String
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
End Class
```

Extract redundant code into subroutines

```
Private Sub CreateUser(ByVal u As User)
    Const InsertQuery As String = _
        "INSERT INTO UserDetails VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')"

    Dim query As String = String.Format(InsertQuery, u.ID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, _
                                                     u.Email, u.Username, u.Password)
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The code then becomes something like this

```
If Not aDataReader2.Read() Then
    CreateUser(user)
ElseIf min = 1 Then
    ...
    user.userID = max + 1
    CreateUser(user)
Else
    ...
    user.userID = min - 1
    CreateUser(user)
    lblResults.Text = "User Account successfully created"
    btnCreateUser.Enabled = False
End If
```

This looks much nicer now.

(My code is not tested, it's just to give you an idea.)

---

**UPDATE**

You cannot read the min and max values like this. Try something like this

```
Dim min, max As Integer

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = _
        New OleDbCommand("SELECT MIN(UserID), MAX(UserID) FROM UserDetails", conn)
    conn.Open()
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        If reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
            ' The table is empty
            min = 1
            max = 1
        Else
            min = reader.GetInt32(0)
            max = reader.GetInt32(1)
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I literally only started learning ASP 4 weeks ago and we have not been shown how to do write the code

Comment: Thank you so much Oliver :) I got it working from what you suggested

Comment: -1 (no vote, just via comment) for the sql injection vulnerable code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Yeah, I know. You just can't teach everything at the same time. I tried to keep it simple. When I can't use command parameters for some reason, I use this function, which is injection safe: `Public Function SqlStr(ByVal s As String) As String :
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then 
            Return "NULL" 
        Else
            Return  "'" & s.Replace("'", "''") & "'"
        End If
    End Function`